# What is the origin of the word "geroff"?

Tags: etymology, slang, origin-unknown

I am not a native speaker so never had a chance to meet the term in the wild, and only seen it in Harry Potter series mostly used by Ron Weasley.

My somewhat corrupted mind assumed it being a shortened version of "bugger off" but recently I've found sources claiming it is somewhat originating from "get off". It sounds more plausible but is there a linguistic rule that   describes such a transformation?

Comment: It comes from dialects which don't enunciate the T at the end of get. "Get off" becomes "Ge off" becomes "Gerroff" because the end of "Ge" doesn't flow into the start of "off" particular well.

Comment: Other consonants can also be "reduced" to **/r/** in sloppy (or stereotypically, *drunken*) speech. For example, ***Yarroo!*** instead of ***Yahoo!*** (which sounds a little "dated" to me, since I first encountered that one in the written form in [Billy Bunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Bunter) children's stories many decades ago). Also quite common is ***Sharrup!*** (= ***Shut up!, Be quiet***), with various spellings.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pieK7b4KLL4 ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers interesting, I've seen it is written as "Shaddup". From this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/525781/6966), it seems that "Shaddup" is American and "Sharrup" is British.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: That rings true. I'd say that *on average*, AmE speakers are more likely than Brits to "reduce" some relatively "awkward" consonant sequence to **/d/**. For example, it's not that uncommon to hear ***Whaddup**?* in some AmE contexts (esp., from AAVE speakers), but I think that version is far less common in the UK (though obviously most people reduce it to ***Whassup**?* on both sides of the pond).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> but recently I've found sources claiming it is somewhat originating from "get off".

This is true, although it is not "somewhat", it is "entirely". https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gerroff#English and https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/geroff/

It is can be written as "Gerroff" as the pronunciation may include a slight "r" sound in the first part and a more noticeable one in the second part - "Ger'roff" - /gɛ(r)rof/

**Gerroff** is a phonetic spelling of "get off" when spoken quickly and/or in an annoyed manner.

> Is there a linguistic rule that describes such a transformation?

"phonetic spelling".

Comment: Good point. There's no actual word "gerroff". If you ask anyone who just said "gerroff" to write down what they just said, they'd write down "get off". (Assuming they didn't just look at you weirdly anyway.) Rowling used it to indicate the way that some of her characters talked.

Comment: @AndyT thank you both, "there is no actual word" explains it perfectly. Looks like similar to the case when "the" is spelled as "da"

Comment: `This is true, although it is not "somewhat", it is "entirely".` I thought you were saying the opposite of what you meant: `This is entirely true, not just "somewhat" true.`

Comment: The referent of "it" is "the word"

Comment: I was just suggesting that instead of using a sentence that needs to be read three times before you can work out what it means, you might want to use simpler language.

Comment: I've always imagined it as the sound you would hear if someone tried to say "get off", but couldn't move their mouth properly, because something was on their face.

Comment: @CJDennis It would be somewhat easier to understand if you first read the sentence which Greybeard quoted and responded to. That earlier sentence provides the context for the "somewhat"..

Comment: @RosieF What makes you think I didn't? I'm in the habit of starting at the beginning, continuing through the middle and finishing at the end.

Answer (score 9):

In some accents of British English, a word-final /t/ sound after a short vowel can be pronounced as something that sounds like an /r/ sound when the following word starts with a vowel. This is discussed on [John Wells's phonetic blog](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/12/t-to-r.html); I quoted the relevant portions in a [previous answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/349536/77227).

"Geroff" is a respelling of the pronunciation of "get off" in such an accent. (I don't know whether the specific form "geroff" might have spread to other speakers who don't have this as a usual feature of their accent.)

The British English "t-to-r" sound change is somewhat similar to the American English phenomenon of "flapped" or "tapped" /t/, but also different in several ways. Wells suggests that "t-to-r" developed by way of /t/ leniting in this position to a voiced flap [ɾ], which was then perceived as /r/, causing it to to be subsequently replaced for some speakers with the now more common [ɹ] allophone of /r/ (just as in words like "very", the [ɾ] allophone of /r/ seems to have become less frequent compared to the [ɹ] allophone).

American English speakers perceive a "flapped/tapped" /t/ as /d/, never (to my knowledge) as /r/. And American English speakers seem to use flap /t/ in more positions: inside of words, and after long vowels/diphthongs. So an American would be more likely to respell "Get off" as "Ged(d)off". Also, from the comments section of the John Wells blog post, it sounds like some British English speakers might have both a t-to-r rule and a separate flapping rule.

Comment: Thank you, your answer resolved my last confusion. Looks like I am more familiar with American English and can recognize the rule with [d] but [r] turned to be a riddle for me.

Comment: ouch. if only I searched for the double-r version I wouldn't have to ask as your other answer explains it already

Comment: I think the British vs. American thing is that, as far as I know, /r/ is not realised as [ɾ] in any widespread American accent, so if an [ɾ] occurs, it can only be interpreted as a t or d, so Americans will only hear it that way (in English at least - Spanish speakers will know [ɾ] as /r/). Although British accents using [ɾ] for intervocalic /r/ are rarer than they used to be, that interpretation is still possible, so there is an overlap between speakers who flap /t/ to [ɾ], and speakers who use [ɾ] for /r/.

Comment: This linguist's surname is *Wells*. Otherwise, good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

From what I know and grew up with, "Gerroff" always meant get off and tended to be from the East Midlands dialect. And we used it sober and drunk, because the further north in England you go the dialect is presumed to get lazier according to some people! For example, in Yorkshire "go to the pub" ends up being shortened to "t' pub".

Comment: It's more a kind of *softened* "tət pub" with the last 't' being really little more than a glottal stop, but  it's not as easy to spell as it is for a Yorkshireman to say ;-) [Native Yorkshireman here]